Dependency Matrix for Flutter Project
I want to create a dependency matrix for a project developed in Flutter.
I used Android Studio to develop this project but I noticed that Android Studio does not make it available in "Code" -> "Analyze Code" -> "Dependecy Matrix" as IntelliJ IDEA does.
So I tried to create this matrix by opening the project on IntelliJ IDEA and, after several errors resolved, I get this massage "No Classes Found - No class files were found for the specified source files. DSM analysis can't be performed." (https://i.sstatic.net/eWw3R7vI.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/eWw3R7vI.png)
What can I do? I can't figure out the problem and can't figure out if I can actually create the dependency matrix on a Flutter project.
Does anyone know how I can do this or have any alternatives?
The dependencies matrix must contain all the dependencies between the ".dart" classes in the project's "lib" folder.
